# Find loop with variable file and path naming

Tags: bash, shell, loops, find

I'm trying to do a bash loop to run a simple process over all files with extension .sam that can be found on a directory and its subdirectories, and use the same name (exc extension) for the output as its input, with output directed to the same folder in which the input was found.

I got to the following:

```
for file in $(find ~/data/finch_data/combruns_BF_genomes -name "*.sam" -type f); do 
    name="${file%.sam}"
    dir=$(pwd $file)
    samtools view -Sb "$dir"/"$name".sam > "$dir"/"$name".bam
done
```

but I'm getting this message:

```
...
>bash:/home/madzays/qsub//home/madzays/data/finch_data/combruns_ZF_transcriptomes/ZBND81X_gff/filteredfirstZBND81X_gff.bam: No such file or directory
>bash:/home/madzays/qsub//home/madzays/data/finch_data/combruns_ZF_transcriptomes/ZBND81X_gff/filteredsecZBND81X_gff.bam: No such file or directory
>bash:/home/madzays/qsub//home/madzays/data/finch_data/combruns_ZF_transcriptomes/ZBND82V_gff/filteredfirstZBND82V_gff.bam: No such file or directory
...
```

What could be wrong?
thanks

Comment: Check the path, it includes `/home/madzays/` twice, which should be incorrect.

Comment: `dir=$(pwd)` not dir=$(pwd $file), but it's not the issue here

Comment: I suggest: `samtools view -Sb "$name.sam" > ...` (without $dir)

Comment: Yeah this worked. But why? I thought find returned only the file name, but it returns the whole path, up to the file name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that `name`variable does not contains what you want. Try getting name with `basename` instead

`for file in $(find ~/data/finch_data/combruns_BF_genomes -name "*.sam" -type f); do name="$(basename $file .sam)" dir=$(pwd $file); samtools view -Sb "$dir"/"$name".sam > "$dir"/"$name".bam; done`

Comment: Yeah. The name variable already included the whole path, up to the file name.